# Increase performance of Stanford-tagger based program

Tags: java, nlp, pos-tagger, stanford-nlp

I just implemented a program that uses the Stanford POS tagger in Java.

I used an input file of a few KB in size, consisting of a few hundred words. I even set the heap size to 600 MB.

But it is still slow and sometimes runs out of heap memory. How can I increase its execution speed and memory performance? I would like to be able to use a few MB as input.

```
  public static void postag(String args) throws ClassNotFoundException

  {

     try

     {

     File filein=new File("c://input.txt");

     String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(filein);

     MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("postagging/wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");

     String tagged = tagger.tagString(content);

        try 
        {
            File file = new File("c://output.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) 
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            } 

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("\n"+tagged);
            bw.close();

            }
              catch (IOException e) 
              {
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }

     } catch (IOException e1)
     {
         e1.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main first piece of advice is to use the `wsj-0-18-left3words-distsim.tagger` (or probably better, the `english-left3words-distsim.tagger` in recent versions, for general text), rather than the `wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger`. While the tagging performance of the bidirectional tagger is *fractionally* better, it is about 6 times slower and uses about twice as much memory. A figure FWIW: on a 2012 MacBook Pro, when given enough text to "warm up" the `left3words` tagger will tag text at about 35000 words per second.

The other piece of advice on memory use is that if you have a large amount of text, make sure you pass it to `tagString()` in reasonable-sized chunks, not all as one huge String, since that whole String will be tokenized at once, adding to the memory requirements.